# Verifying that the Sequence $\frac{4n-1}{5n}$ is Bounded and Increasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have the sequence

$$\bigg(\dfrac{4n-1}{5n}\bigg) \qquad n \in \{1,2, \ldots \}$$

I want to show that this sequence is increasing and bounded above, so that I can use the bounded monotone convergence theorem. It is very obvious to me that this function is increasing and bounded, but I am not sure how to prove this. Usually when I see these types of problems they are phrased in a form such as $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ which I am comfortable work with. Is there any way to phrase my problem such that the $n+1$ term relates to the $n$ term?

Comment: Here, as is often the case, it helps to simplify your expression first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have $a_n = \frac{4}{5}-\frac{1}{5n} < \frac{4}{5}$

Because $\frac{1}{5n} > \frac{1}{5(n+1)}$, then $a_n < a_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Do you HAVE to do it using Weierstrass Monotone Convergence theorem? It's simpler to compute the limit: $$\lim\left( \frac{4n-1}{5n} \right)=\lim\left(\frac{4}{5}-\frac{1}{5n} \right)=\frac{4}{5}.$$

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on expressing $a_{n+1}$ as a function of $a_n$, you could say
$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{15 a_n - 16}{25 a_n - 25}$$

Comment: How does this help show either bounded or increasing?

Answer (score 3):

$a_n
=\dfrac{4n-1}{5n}
$.

Proceeding very naively,

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n+1}-a_n
&=\dfrac{4(n+1)-1}{5(n+1)}-\dfrac{4n-1}{5n}\\
&=\dfrac{4n+3}{5n+5}-\dfrac{4n-1}{5n}\\
&=\dfrac{(4n+3)(5n)-(4n-1)(5n+5)}{(5n+5)5n}\\
&=\dfrac{(20n^2+15n)-(20n^2+15n-5)}{(5n+5)5n}\\
&=\dfrac{5}{(5n+5)5n}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{(n+1)5n}\\
&> 0\\
\end{array}
$

so the terms are increasing.

Also,
using the canonical telescoping series,

$a_{n+1}-a_n
=\dfrac15\dfrac{1}{(n+1)n}
=\dfrac15\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)
$
and it telescopes.